# 55KB of JQUERY is too big for my application

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there any way to truncate jQuery?

I need to use only AJAX related methods in jQuery code.

As you might know the minified version is only 55KB and the uncompressed version is about 110KB.

Comment: I've been wondering why its 55 KB, the jquery.com homepage says the production version is 19 KB

Comment: I think 19kb is the size after gzipping

Comment: I'd be really interested to know why 55K is considered 'too big'

Comment: Why don't they host a gzipped version..........?

Comment: HTTP content is gzipped on-demand if the server supports it (most do) and has it enabled and the browser request header includes Accept-Encoding: gzip (most do). A pre-gzipped version wouldn't be of any additional benefit because it would be the same size as gzipping it on-demand.

Comment: You could just use a small AJAX function without having all of Jquery loaded. There are plenty out there that are WAY less than 55kb. All of the js on my site totals about 100kb, and my AJAX function isn't even 1kb

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I think the answer to your question is 'probably not'.

But consider these points:

- You don't have to serve it on every page request, sensible HTTP response headers should mean it only needs to be downloaded once per client browser.
- If you use the Google CDN for jQuery, your client may not need to download it at all, as there is a very good chance they will already have it cached.

i.e.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Considering the different versions of jquery and cache sizes I think "very good" is a bit of an exaggeration .

Answer (score 10):

Using gzip compression it brings it down to 19kb. It's going to be cached from there on out, so I'm not sure why it's an issue. That's far less than most decent sized images.

Using a CDN is also an option if you don't mind someone else hosting your code and your issue is just overall bandwidth.

Answer (score 6):

Is there a reason why you need to make it smaller?  Coming in at a size of 55kb is rather insignificant nowadays.

If you need it faster, try having it link off of Google, it's always cached on their server.  Look at their documentation [here](http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxlibs/documentation/#jquery).

You can also try downloading your Javascript files asynchronously.

Comment: There are still a lot of people out there using dial-up, and 55Kb is a little painful for those users.

Comment: That is true (I think it's something like 1/3 people in the US, but don't quote me on that).  Question is, is it a connection speed issue, or are there other areas for optimization, for example, managing your ViewState if it's an Asp.net application.

Answer (score 2):

You can go to an older code base if it suits your needs.

1.2.6 packed is 30KB
1.1.4 compressed is 22KB

Answer (score 2):

You can try to build your own jQuery from source. jQuery is actually cut into little modules and you could try to disable some of them when building your own jQuery.

If you only need AJAX, you may not need DOM manipulation, CSS utilities or animations.

Answer (score 1):

Um, why is jQuery too big? How large are your pages?

What you should be doing is forcing the client to cache it so it's only downloaded once. You do this by setting the Expires header often accompanied with versioning the file so you can force a reload if necessary.

You could manually prune the code but that's probably going to be a huge headache.